# Why does Windows reset my UEFI settings with every update?

Tags: windows-10, uefi, lenovo-laptop, hotkeys

Every time there's a Windows update, my UEFI settings reset to the default. Most of these are fine (timing and boot work well on the defaults), but the one that really irks me is the "hotkey" mode - function keys no longer function as functions keys, that is, F1 will not be read as F1 but rather as the mute/unmute button. If I wish to actually press F1, I have to press Fn + F1.

I find that behavior irksome, so I disable it in UEFI, and my F1 key is again an F1 key... until the next update when I have to change it again.

Why is Windows messing with my UEFI settings, and how can I prevent it from doing so?

Comment: Windows does not reset or change any UEFI settings itself. It can actually only be that the UEFI setting is reset by another constellation, such as there:
https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkBook-Notebooks/Fx-Hotkeys-option-resets-after-every-wake-up-from-sleep/m-p/4623621

Comment: How old is the laptop? May be the BIOS battery that provides the power for keeping the BIOS settings alive is weak?

Comment: Laptop is less than a year old so I doubt the CMOS battery is an issue. And this doesn't happen when I wake up the laptop, only after Windows updates. Still, I'll try updating the firmware and see if it helps the issue.

Comment: Well I did another Windows update and it reset my UEFI settings again. Now it also prevents me from disabling the touchpad using the function keys, so I had to go into Devic Manager to do so.